# More information from Barcode

Tags: ios, barcode

I was using this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-barcode-metadata-reader-ios/ 
everything went fine but the information that label is showing is only type of bar code but it is too poor information that for example user would like too see, user don`t need a type of bar code, user need more information, for example what kind of fruit is it, what price is it and such a lot information, is there any way to get more information from bar code, i`d like app too show for example name of fruit, for example banana or orange or other names of fruits or prices of them

Comment: I know this question makes no sense but it's so cute how he thinks barcodes work

Answer (score 1):

You're joking, right? a barcode is just a number. It has no meaning until you read the number from a database.
If you want to get information on an item you must then check against a database for that number (like amazon's product api).

Even then, every store or business can have an internal barcode that is not unique and it will have a different meaning on every database you read it from.

Comment: i`m not joking, i just didn`t know that i cant get info from numbers, and how can i get info from database from that number of barcode?

Comment: what would i do for it?

Comment: You need to find out where you're going to get the data from (like Amazon, a local store's server, your own server...), read their documentation to find out what you need to make that network call, then make the network call , and parse the data that comes back. If you need help with any of these steps, google them and then post specific questions here (stack overflow, not this thread) if you get stuck on a specific step